# Zend Framework won't work for URLs with trailing slash -- how to configure nginx to rewrite URLs properly?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, zend-framework

I am setting up an `nginx` server to be used with the Zend Framework. For the most part it works. However, if there is a trailing slash on the end of a URL, for example `http://localhost/test/` vs `http://localhost/test`, the URL with a trailing slash will *not* work. This is unexpected and unfortunate. I want it to work for both URLs.

What should I do to resolve this? My nginx configuration is:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root /var/www/site/public;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/site/public/index.php;
      }

}
```

As you can see I've tried to add a rewrite condition but it isn't seeming to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pair of config files that I use for Zend Framework applications.  First, `php.conf`, which I share between projects on my development workstation. I keep this at a directory above my `sites` directory, right in the nginx config root (e.g. `/usr/local/etc/nginx/php.conf`):

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
# this will allow Nginx to intercept 4xx/5xx error codes
# Nginx will only intercept if there are error page rules defined
# -- This is better placed in the http {} block as a default
# -- so that in the case of wordpress, you can turn it off specifically
# -- in that virtual host's server block

location ~ \.php$
{
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV   development;

    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT     $document_root;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME       $server_name;

    fastcgi_read_timeout            60;

    fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_index                   index.php;
}
```

And then the `server` block that makes use of that:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name local.example.com;

    root /var/www/example/public;

    location /
    {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    include php.conf;
}
```

In your case, I think the key bit is `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`, where we just pass the URL and query string wholesale to `index.php`, and let it do the parsing.

Comment: There are two important parts here: `try_files` and `fastcgi_split_path_info`.